# post array empty submit

Tags: php, mysql, html, submit

Hi I am trying to submit a form but when I do:

```
    var_dump($_POST);
```

I get: Array(0) { }

```
    <form action="avvikelse.php" method="POST" />
    <p>Operation step: <input type="int" name"operation_step" /></p>
    <p>Problem detail: <input type="text" name"problem_detail" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Why?

Thank you!

Comment: You should try removing the forward slash from the `<form>` tag ... the  browser is assuming an empty form

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML in your form is malformed.

```
<form action="avvikelse.php" method="post">
<p>Operation step: <input type="text" name="operation_step" /></p>
<p>Problem detail: <input type="text" name="problem_detail" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```